# Sonar Issue for access SchemaFactory to validate xml with XSD file

Tags: java, xml, sonarqube, xsd-validation

I am validating xml file with `XSD` and I am getting sonar issue for SchemaFactory object creation
`XML parsers should not be vulnerable to XXE attacks` so I have set the below properties

```
schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

but when I run the code, then I am getting the `http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD is not recognized.`
error, Please help me to figure out the issue.

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    schemaFactory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
    try {
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(getResource(schemaFile)));

        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(getResource(xmlFile))));
        return true;
    } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
        xsdInvalidData.add(xmlFile + "=" + e.getMessage());
        logger.error(xmlFile + "invalid xsd and enter in catch " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: SchemaFactory is a JAXP API with multiple implementations. You need to tell us what implementation you are using. (The actual class name of the schemaFactory object would be a start; we may need to ask about software versions as well.)

Comment: JDK 1.8 version's javax/xml/validation/schemaFactory.java class we are using to validate xml files with xsd files.

Comment: @MahiMokhashi hello, have you got answer to this issue? Am facing same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory` doesn't support anything. You'll probably need to find a different implementation.

```
public void setProperty(String name, Object object)
    throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {

    if (name == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("the name parameter is null");
    }
    throw new SAXNotRecognizedException(name);
}
```